# Does DI in Angular concern any external resource?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm discovering Angular 7 and I was wondering how to use DI the best way.

My question is basically: should *any* object needed by a given component be injected?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no. I mean, services have certainly to be injected, because this is just a usual pattern.

But if for example a component needs a helper class, should this class be injected, like so:

```
import {CameraDimensionsHelper} from <file path>;

constructor (private cameraDimensions: CameraDimensionsHelper) {}
```

...or should it just be instanciated in a more "classical" way when needed, like so:

```
import {CameraDimensionsHelper} from <file path>;

private myMethod() {
  const cameraDimensions = new CameraDimensionsHelper();
}
```

Thank you for you advice.

Comment: what do you mean a helper class ? how is that different from a service ?

Comment: DI's main advantages are the ability to easily share a single instance between several components, to use a mock instance in tests, to provide an alternative implementation for the service. If you might want one of these for your CameraDimensionsHelper, then use a service. Otherwise, it doesn't matter much

Comment: @Stavm: interresting question, indeed. In a "philosophical" way, any helper is made to serve, so that it can be considered as a service. In an architectural way, I consider myself a service as an object part of the Service Layer (which in turn is part of the Model Layer). As an example, in Java you can't consider the `StringUtils` helper class as a service, yet it's intensively used by other classes...

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the usage of the helper class. If the helper is specific for a single component, then you can create an instance of the Class. If the helper classes serves utility methods to multiple components, it is better to make it an `@Injectable()` and use DI.

Comment: That's quite an arbitrary rule. Why couldn't you just create e new instance in every component? That's really not what I would use as a rule to decide whether to create a service or not.

Comment: If a service is used by multiple components, why would you want to create multiple instances of it, each of which would serve the same purpose ?

Comment: Maybe because the class is stateful. If it's stateless and only contains helper methods, why create an instance at all and not make the methods static?